# catch $ajax json type post data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var ajaxData = {1: a, 2: b, 3: c, 4: d};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data : ajaxData,
        etc
        etc
```

if I use `dataType: 'json'` in $ajax, how can I catch the data in my php? if not I can use $_POST['1'] etc but I plan to use jason because I have to do `$_POST['2']` and more..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**dataType: json**  is the return data type of the ajax call

**data** are the parameters that your php file/servlet will be expecting.  to pass a json see example below, its a mixed of json and normal parameters

```
var params = {a:1, 
              b:2, 
              myJSON: JSON.stringify({data1:1, data2:2, data3:3})}
    jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "some/url/of/php/file",
                    data: params,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response){
                        // this should catch what ever is returned by your php file
                        alert(response)
                    },
                    error: function(msg) {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
```

In your php file you can access the data being passed is like this $_POST['a'], $_POST['b'], $_POST['myJSON']

dataType is the return type of your php file not the parameters being sent to the php file.

refer here for more information
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: ok, now the problem in php side, I have to check them 1 by 1? I mean like isset($_POST['1'])

Comment: isset() check if a parameter is being passed in the post or get requests.  Basing in my example if you want to check if parameter a, b and myJSON is being passed you have to say
`if(isset($_POST['myJSON'])){`
`/* do something here with the myJSON */}`

Comment: so just can check the entire json? have to do the validation in client side?

Comment: To check the content of your json you have to decode it first.  Check this link about json in PHP
http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Answer (score 0):

You will have a php parameter in the request named data which will be parsed to Json, then you only need to apply:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with

```
$.ajax(
    ...
    data: {data: JSON.stringify({1: a, 2: b, 3: c, 4: d};)}
)
```

And then on the server side I'd use json_decode function to get the data